# Uncaught exception: Each data element must implement a unique 'id' property slick.dataview.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I wrote a code to access data from a RESTFUL service into dataView to populate into Slick Grid table.

I am getting an error  that each data element must implement a Unique Id Property!

I am passing a unique id to the data view while setting the data into data view but nothing is happening.

```
    var dataView;
    var grid;
    var data;
    var options = {
    forceFitColumns: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false,
    autoExpandColumns: true
    };

    var columns = [{
    id: "userId",
    name: "User Id",
    field: "userId"
    }, {
    id: "id",
    name: "Id",
    field: "id"

    }, {
    id: "title",
    name: "Title",
    field: "title"

    }, {
    id: "completed",
    name: "Completed",
    field: "completed"

    }];

    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        data = JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log("received data " + JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error while getting data");
    }
    });

    dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();

    dataView.beginUpdate();
    dataView.setItems(data, "id");
    dataView.endUpdate();


    grid = new Slick.Grid('#slickGrid', dataView, columns, options);

    // Make the grid respond to DataView change events.

    dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    alert("1");
    grid.updateRowCount();
    grid.render();
    });


    dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    alert("2");
    grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
    grid.render();
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4UyNA/116/) HERE

Comment: Am not sure how this works. On your fiddle I passed the response directly as object than stringified. I also had to set the height of the viewport as it was making the height:0. Still it shows only two rows and when u click one row another appears. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/4UyNA/117/). Hope this helps you to go ahead.

Comment: Thanks @anpsmn . Now it works, i guess the problem was because of height only .

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.parse` and then pass it to set items

```
data=JSON.parse(data);
dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(data, "id");
```